# Query help: Get repeating value once with max ID

Tags: oracle

In the below query, I want the CPNY_ID to come only once for the maximum value of ID (2 in this case). Preferably, I do not want to use any subquery.

--Edit start
If I may rephrase my question, If, I am getting multiple matches from table t_ref when I join it with table t_main. I want only match from t_ref with maximum ID value.
--Edit complete

Could you please suggest better options?

```
create table t_main (id number, org_id number, aid number);
insert into t_main values(1,100,10);
insert into t_main values(2,200,20);
insert into t_main values(3,300,30);

create table t_ref (id number, cpny_id number, bid number);
insert into t_ref values(1,100,10);
insert into t_ref values(2,100,20);
insert into t_ref values(3,300,30);
insert into t_ref values(4,500,40);

commit;

select a.id, a.org_id, b.cpny_id  from t_main a inner join t_ref b on a.aid = b.bid;

--Result
ID  ORG_ID  CPNY_ID
1     100       100
2     200       100
3     300       300
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT MAX(a.id), MAX(a.org_id), b.cpny_id 
FROM t_main a 
INNER JOIN t_ref b 
ON a.aid = b.bid
GROUP BY b.cpny_id
```

Comment: Thankyou, this works. I have one further question. what if ORG_ID has string values instead of number?

Comment: If I may rephrase my question, I am getting multiple matches from table t_ref when I join it with table t_main. I want only match from t_ref with maximum ID value.

Comment: You must provide some sample data for this. BTW FYI, Max will work with string values.

Comment: If I am not wrong, MAX on string value will act in alphabetical order. Anyways, thank you for the earlier answer.

Comment: "Max will work in alphabetic order"  Not quite. `MAX()` against strings works on ASCII order. So this is while this true - `'C' > 'B'` - this is also true `'a' > 'B'`. And, of course, if you're dealing with alphanumeric strings remember that  `'2' > '11'` is true.